# TypeError: Cannot read property '$http' of undefined - quasar

Tags: vue.js, axios, quasar-framework

I was looking for a solution on the internet but nothing worked. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I try importin index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Axios from '../boot/axios'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(axios)
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(Axios)

axios.js:
import axios from 'axios'

export default async ({
  Vue
}) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  if (token) {
    Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}` }

  axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response
  }, function (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      // refreshtoken
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  })
  Vue.prototype.$http = axios
}
```

TypeError: Cannot read property '$http' of undefined

Comment: repository.js: const baseDomain = 'https://localhost:44397'
const baseURL = `${baseDomain}/api/`

export default this.$http.create({
  baseURL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
  }
})

Answer (score 1):

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Axios from '../boot/axios'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(axios)
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(Axios)

axios.js:
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.prototype.$http = axios

export default async ({
  Vue
}) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  if (token) {
    Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}` }

  axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response
  }, function (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      // refreshtoken
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  })

}
```

you should define Vue.prototype.$http = axios before use Vue.prototype.$http